# Dynamically determining which link was clicked with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, hyperlink

So I'm working on a dashboard (one page) type application, and I have a set of links:

```
<a href = "#">3s01</a>
<a href = "#">5e02</a>
<a href = "#">2k01</a>
<a href = "#">3a01</a>
<a href = "#">5j01</a>
etc...
```

The way the text in between the tags is populated is by grabbing the data from an xml file using JQuery.  Because the xml file can change, the links aren't static.  My task is to be able to click on a link and figure out what the text between the  tags is, so that I can populate a table on the page accordingly.  The only problem is I don't know how to get that data using JQuery/Javascript/html/whatever.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[href=#]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

But if you `a` are dynamically generated that means, generate after DOM ready then you should try

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href=#]', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

Here instead of `body` you can use `ANY Valid Selector` that is parent of `a` tags which belongs to DOM already.

Read more about **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

Comment: This should work better as the `on(` will handle the dynamically loaded content

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss huh.. no it doesn't.. The above `.on` syntax doesn't handle dynamic contents.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: No it doesn't.

Comment: oops, my bad :) forgot to note it should be `$(document).on('click','a' function() {`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: True, though binding delegate handlers to a "global" container isn't good.

Comment: No, but we don't know the parent of the OP's links to enhance the binding.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I probably should have said *usually* isn't good. Sometimes it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` in the handler.

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function() { alert(this); });
```

---

To get the text, use `.text()`...

```
alert($(this).text());
```

---

Or the not officially supported yet faster version, `$.text()`...

```
alert($.text([this]));
```